# Change ASPX content type

Tags: c#, asp.net, tags, include, execute

I'm trying to force ASP.NET to render restored asp tags from database.

I saved this (for example) to database `hello <%= Generate(1) %>` as a string and looking for a way to render it after restore. I tried `Response.Write` to write this code to a page and include this page in destination but what I got was exactly `hello <%= Generate(1) %>` and not `hello sam`.

Is there any way to change the include page content type to tell the destination to render restored asp tags?

I tried both `include`  and `HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute` but non of them render the tags

Comment: First of all `<%= Generate(1) %>` itself is equivalent to `Response.Write('Generate(1)')` but the problem is you need to define `Generate(1)` in your code behind file. It won't render automatically.

Comment: Dear @RahulSingh,  '<%= Generate(1) %>' is restored in database with this shape '<'  and '%' and.... I want to run it, Imaging Generate() Method is known and I defined it before in code behind.